# How to remove a list of accidently deleted databases from Sql Server Management Studio's tree-like list?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have accidently deleted my database files using Windows Explorer.

Now I want to remove these databases from SQL Server Management Studio' tree-like list.

The following screenshot shows the database names (musics and silverlight) I want to remove.

[image]

I attempted to delete them one by one but I got an error for each attempt. The following screenshot just shows my attempt to delete musics:

[image]

These orphan names really upsets my eyes and can produce misunderstanding in the future.
Is there any way to remove these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like they are already deleted but just still showing in the Databases tree - did you try to right-click on Databases node and select Refresh?

Comment: Well done. Thank you so much! I wonder why I did not anticipate your solution. :-)