# How do I remove deleted databases from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a similar problem to this one here : [How to remove a list of accidently deleted databases from Sql Server Management Studio's tree-like list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435204/how-to-remove-a-list-of-accidently-deleted-databases-from-sql-server-management) 
but the provided solution to that question hasn't helped me.

I have a number of database .mdf files that were created (and subsequently deleted from the folder) by VS's web testing.

My SSMS is now chock full of .mdf database files that no longer exist that I can't get rid of.

[image: List of mdf files]

Current things I have tried (to no avail):
1. Refreshing the databases (at every level of the tree)
2. Right-click and deleting the databases. I receive the error:
[image: SQLServer error message]
3. Recreating the file in the given folder structure (Still doesn't recognise it)

If possible I'd like to avoid having to completely reinstall SS all over again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159477/how-to-delete-database-from-sql-server-if-mdf-and-ldf-file-is-removed-from-the

Comment: what kind of databases are these.never seen before

Comment: The databases are .mdf files that are creatd when using a Datasource in Visual Studio web tests - but they shuold effectively be similar to most database mdf files as far as I know.

I tried the suggestion in Ivan's link, but I still get the error message : "Cannot drop the database ''D:\DEV\MAPPING\PERFORMANCE TESTING\TESTRESULTS\DJEFFERY_9LBPQ92 2017-02-20 15_25_52\OUT\PERFTESTDATABASE.MDF'', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Comment: Try this scenario: https://superuser.com/questions/737598/cant-detach-database-in-sql-server-management-studio-after-accidentally-deleted

Comment: Still no joy, I'm afraid.
I forgot to mention that these files are showing up in the LoclDB (rather than the default SS instance) - so thats in: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
I dont know if that makes a difference or not - probably not. The files are generated by the Visual Studio Load Test software.

Originally I thought it was because I was using an .mdf file rather than a proper DB, but having now tried using a full DB with my load tests, it is still generating these files.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Accidentally deleted a database and could not get it removed from the list in SSMS.

In SSMS right click on database then "Delete". Ignore the error, press "Cancel" in dialog. Then right click on database again, choose "Policies"->"Delete Health States". Refresh the instance databases and the database should not be in the list.

Comment: This gave me the same permissions errors that I had dropping the non-existent database in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Open a query window on the master database, then:

```
Select * from sys.databases where state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
```

Will give you a list of databases.

Then for each database in the name column of the query result, you can do:

```
drop database mydatabasename
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and came upon this post whilst looking for a solution.  So adding my two pennies worth in case it helps someone else.

The solution that worked for me was to DETACH the databases. e.g.

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'tmp8E8C', 'true';
```

Where the first argument is the name of the database and the second argument is to "skip checks".  If "skip checks" was false then it would update statistics but as the database files no longer exist on disk that would be a bit pointless :)

For reference see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If you need to DETACH all user databases then you could use something like the below, which is what I used to sort out the cluster fudge I had created!

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE LEN(owner_sid) > 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(128) = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE LEN(owner_sid) > 1)
    EXECUTE sp_detach_db @DbName, 'true'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found a solution, maybe it will help somebody

If your database files are already deleted, but SSMS thinks that the database still exists, you can right-click on the database and choose 'Tasks' > 'Detach' to remove it from the list